# jqModal question

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I am trying to implement a modal window using jqModal plug-in. I make an ajax call to populate a div with tabular data. In there, there is a clickable progress bar.

In my script, I have

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('#jqmRTypes').jqm({modal:true});


       showTypes = function(id,projNum) {
       formData = 'vw=getTypes&ID='+id+'&project_number='+projNum;
       alert(formData);
       $.ajax({
          type: "get",        
          url: "<cfoutput>#actURL#</cfoutput>",
          data: formData,        
          cache: false,       
           success: function(result) { 
               $("#jqmRTypesText").html(result);
               $('#jqmRTypes').jqmShow();
            },
           error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
            confirm('Error!' + err );
           }
        }); 
   }
```

I don't know why but I keep getting an error in firebug (no description and points to $('#jqmRTypes').jqmShow();) 
I can put show() instead of jqmShow() and i will see the window, but it's no longer modular.

It's driving me nuts. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grrr. I wrote a custom tag to display a progress bar. Depending on the work completed, it displays a bar with a percentage. Within this tag, I had:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
```

Once I removed this line, it worked perfectly fine.